# ES - Convert Legacy ElasticSearch from Rest to High level Client

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm wondering what is the equivalent for the following query with elastic 5 - 7 (doesn't matter for me)

I know that this query has deprecated but actually i'm trying to use legacy 1.7.5 cluster work with High level ES cluster.
I did some tests and although the documentation points that it isn't support i tried and most of the simple actions work. What is left is convert some queries like in the example below

```
   {
  "size" : 3000,
  "query" : {
  "filtered" : {
    "filter" : {
      "bool" : {
        "must" : [ {
          "terms" : {
            "source" : [ "o365mail" ]
          }
        }, {
          "range" : {
            "bckdate" : {
              "from" : "1549360021398l",
              "to" : null,
              "include_lower" : true,
              "include_upper" : true
            }
          }
        } ]
      }
    }
  }
  },
  "fields" : "*"
}
```

What i've tried so far is with `7.9.3`:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.9/java-rest-high.html

```
SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();
        boolQueryBuilder
                .must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery(IndexFields.SOURCE.getIndexName(),Arrays.asList(Source.O365MAIL.toString().toLowerCase())))
                .must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("bckdate").gte(1549360021398l).lte(null));

        sourceBuilder.query(boolQueryBuilder);
        SearchRequest sr = new SearchRequest();
        sr.source(sourceBuilder);
        SearchResponse searchResponse2 = client.search(sr, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

The query from debugging is:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "terms" : {
          "source" : [
            "o365mail"
          ],
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      },
      {
        "range" : {
          "bckdate" : {
            "from" : 1549360021398,
            "to" : null,
            "include_lower" : true,
            "include_upper" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

Im wondering if it is the same regarding the filters of the legacy code, cause the responded data is pretty the same .

I need not to break the logic with all `Filters` like in legacy query...

thanks for help

Comment: interesting but I don't think its a simple one, you need to do a lot more work as filtered queries are deprecated in lastest ES version.

Comment: @Elasticsearch Ninja - so maybe not to take the last version of rest client , maybe 5.6 version is enough not to break the logic ??

Comment: try maybe a query_string query? like: 

"source:(\"o365mail\") AND bcdate:[1549360021398 TO *]"

the logic seems simple enough for it to work.